# "plugging in" infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, education, infinity

Do you allow your undergraduate calculus students to "plug in" infinity when evaluating a limit at infinity?

For example, would you accept the notation: $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac1x=\frac1\infty=0$?

There is disagreement among my colleagues.

I'm in the camp that does not accept this abuse of notation for three main reasons:

1. Infinity is not a constant and therefore direct substitution does not apply.
2. "Plugging in" infinity defeats the very notion of a limit because we no longer see the concept of the unbounded variable if the variable has been replaced.
3. This may lead to further misunderstanding of the concept of a limit.

Comment: I would agree that "plugging in infinity" kind of defeats the purpose of the idea of a limit. Instead, ask them to see how the function behaves upon plugging in arbitrarily large numbers on their calculators. This captures the intuition behind the idea of a limit without allowing them to abuse notation, whether intentional or not. It also leads you nicely into rigorous limit definitions.

Comment: You will get a lot of different opinions to this question. Can you try rephrasing it so it not an opinion based question.

Comment: I think that if you explain it as $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac1x=\frac{1}{\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x}=\frac1\infty=0$ then it's reasonable, since obviously $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x=\infty$.

Comment: Theoretically, if a student knows what he is writing then I am okay with that. However, this is not a regular case...

Comment: I think a student should just write $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} = 0$ and leave it be. Personally, I wouldn't deduct marks for not justifying that; it's sort of obvious. In any case, it's imperative that a calculus prof should explain very clearly that, within the context of the real number system, $\infty$ is used to refer to a limiting process, not an actual number.

Comment: Thank you, Ian Miller, for your feedback. Forgive me for loading this question. I did so because I was interested to know if anyone has any particular refutation of any of the concerns I expressed.

Comment: I accept that $\frac{1}{\infty}=0$, but there will be punishment if a student writes $\frac{1}{0}=\infty$, unless they clearly state that $\infty$ is the one-point compactifier of the reals (or of the complexes).  However, those who are plugging in $\infty$ must know which kinds of algebraic manipulations are defined.  If they write $\infty-\infty=0$, then they will be punished.

Comment: I think it is doing students a disservice by teaching them they can just substitute it. From my experience teaching post 16 it is better to teach what the methods are actually doing, to begin to develop an understanding and mathematical reasoning. I've seen a lot of students who can do the math but have no appreciation why it works. IMO, teaching them they can substitute $\infty$ doesn't help them appreciate that $\infty$ is very different to numbers. Especially at undergrad, there's no substitute for just teaching the proper method and not shortcuts that disguise the math

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would belong **much much better** on the Mathematics Educators stack exchange (http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm in the camp that does not accept this abuse of notation for three main reasons:

I don't really agree that this is an abuse of notation, but as far as I know, you only really get "half" the result you're looking for like this.

Let me explain.

Let $P$ denote the set obtained by adjoining a point called $\infty$ to $\mathbb{R}$. This can be made into a topological space in the usual way, thereby making $\mathbb{R}$ into a topological circle. Each partial function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defines a function $\hat{f} : P \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(P)$ as follows: $y \in \hat{f}(x)$ iff there exists a sequence $X$ in the domain of $f$ such that $X$ converges to $x$ in $P$ and $f(x)$ converges to $y$ in $P$. This can in turn be extended to a function $\hat{f} : \mathcal{P}(P) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(P)$ by writing $\hat{f}(A) = \{\hat{f}(a) : a \in A\}.$

For example:

$$\frac{1}{0} = \infty, \qquad \frac{1}{\infty} = 0$$

Similar things can be done with multi-input partial functions $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, like division. We get equations like $$\frac{\infty}{\infty} = P.$$

With these definitions, we can safely reason as follows:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} y \in (x:=x_0)y$$

for any $x_0 \in P$, where $(x:=x_0)$ means the result of replacing every copy of $x$ with $x_0$ i.e. uniform substitution.

For example, the following reasoning is perfectly valid

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{5+(1/x)}{x} \in \frac{5+(1/\infty)}{\infty} = \frac{5+0}{\infty} = \frac{5}{\infty} = 0$$

This tells us that if the limit exists, then it's zero. What it seems not to tell us is that the limit actually exists.

Thoughts/comments everyone?

Comment: I agree that this notation is acceptable in the context of the extended real number line, but typically, students use this notation without knowledge of topology. One of my colleagues defines and explains this to his undergraduate calculus students and only then allows this notation.